# Kак сделать вывод всего текста из файла

Tags: python

Короче, писал код на поиск данных в текстовом файле,  пользователя спрашивают что нужно найти и это ищется в файле, но работает не так, как я хотел.

Допустим значение `1`, и код должен выводить все `1`, то есть, если содержимое текстового файла числа от 1-20, то выводиться должны: `1`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`, `15`, `16`, `17`, `18`, `19` (это отдельные строки в файле).

Код:

```
search = input('запрос:')
f = open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8')
result = f.read()
f.close()
c = result.count(search)
while c > 0:
    print(search)
    c = 1
```

Comment: Вопрос невнятный, попробуйте сформулировать получше, дать пример.

Comment: Нужно чтобы выводились все совпадения а не только запрос

Comment: Дай пару примеров, что должно выводиться, если пользователь ввел 1. И почему. И посмотри что ты печатаешь в строчке ``print(search)`` и чему равна эта переменная.

Comment: search значение присваевает пользователь через input. А выводится должны все значения  у которых есть 1 в айди пользователя например

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка "Править", Все дополнения туда.

Comment: 1. если ты пишешь ``print(search)``, а в search содержится то, что ввел пользователь, то почему ты думаешь, что вдруг выведется что-то другое? 2. Если хочешь выводить какие-то другие значения, то нужно для начала эти значения найти, а не просто сосчитать сколько раз встречается в файле текст, который ввел пользователь.

Comment: Можно сделать `readlines` и потом этот список перебрать, ища в каждой строке искомое.

Comment: А как это сделать , я и создал вопрос

Comment: `for result in f.readlines():` и дальше ваш код с отступом. Вообще это элементарная задача, такое вы должны сами писать, почитав таториалы. Пользы от таких вопросов-ответов немного.

Comment: Хотя я может вообще не то вам советую. Вопрос очень нечётко сформулирован. Добавьте в вопрос примеры входных данных и что должно быть на выходе.

Comment: `то выводиться должны` А что это - отдельные строки текстового файла? Отдельные числа на одной строке? Ещё что-то?

Comment: MBo, это отдельные строки

Comment: Хорошо, тогда обойдите все строки по отдельности, проверяйте на вхождение "1" с помощью `in`

Comment: А как проверить можете код написать?

Comment: https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operator-vhozhdenija-chlenstva-in-python/

Comment: Проще  всего (и скорее  будет работать быстрее) вызвать команду `grep` и передать ей в параметрах что и где искать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
search = input('запрос: ')
with open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        if search in line:
            print(line)             # или  print(line[:-1])  или  print(line.strip())
```

---

Объяснение:

1. Лучше применить `with`, чем вручную закрывать файл. Файл закроется автоматически после выхода из `with`.
2. `search in line` значит, что строка `search` находится в строке `line`, чего вы и хотите.
3. В переменной `line` будет вся строка, включая символ перехода на новую строку (`\n`). Потому для отсутствия лишней пустой строки после каждого `print(line)` может быть более удобным вывести отдельные строки без последнего символа: `print(line[:-1])` или `print(line.strip())`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот:

```py
search = input('Запрос: ')
with open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
[print(line.strip(), end=' ') for line in lines if line.count(search)]
```

Comment: Лучше уж тогда через `join` печатайте. Использовать списковые сокращения, если вам не нужен итоговый список - это не очень хороший стиль.